# Mockito Mocks Behaving Like Spies: Kotlin

Tags: junit, mockito, kotlin

I'm working on a kotlin jar in which I am attempting to mock an input to a function

```
class MyService
fun serviceFunction(input: ClassFromAnotherLibrary): Output {
  val foo = input.memberFunction()
```

It just so happens that `memberFunction` has been added to that class in my package via an package-level extension function

```
fun ClassFromAnotherLibrary.memberFunction() : Foo {
  val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
  return mapper.readValue(this.serializedFoo, Foo::class.java)
}
```

Now I want to write a test for the `serviceFunction`, but I want to mock out the `memberFunction` call (I have separate tests for that).

So in my Mockito JUnit test, I do the following

```
val service = Service()
val mockClassFromAnotherLibrary = mock<ClassFromAnotherLibrary>()
val mockFoo = mock<Foo>()

whenever(mockClassFromAnotherLibrary.memberFunction())
  .thenReturn(mockFoo)

service.serviceFunction(mockClassFromAnotherLibrary)
```

I would expect that `memberFunction`'s actual implementation would never get called, and that my mock would intercept any attempts to call it and instead return my `mockFoo`.

What's *actually* happening is the `whenever` setup to mock out the method *is invoking the underlying function*, causing a `NullPointerException` when the `mapper` tries to read `serializedFoo` (which is of course null).

My question is: **why on earth is the real `memberFunction` being executed??** I'm new to Mockito and Kotlin, but have used Jasmine (for JS) and Spock (for Groovy / Java) testing in the past, and mocking out an object in both of those frameworks would *never actually execute* any mocked-out function (that I'm aware of).

I've been able to work around issues similar to this in the past by making the `ClassFromAnotherLibrary` I'm trying to mock have an `interface` that I mock instead, but that

1. Feels hacky, and
2. Isn't an option in this case (it's not my class to edit, it's coming from another library)

For reference, these are the relevant gradle dependencies my project is using:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.8.9"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.9"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.9"

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.1.4-3"
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.1.4-3"
testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.3.0"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47"
```

I also have set up a `MockMaker` file in my `test/resources` folder to enable `mock-maker-inline`, though I don't totally understand what it is that might accomplish (saw a tip about it [here](https://antonioleiva.com/mockito-2-kotlin/))

Thanks to any Kotlin/Mockito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension functions are nothing but a regular Java static method and as far as I remember, Mockito cannot mock static methods.

Comment: You're saying a Kotlin extension function (which has access to `this`) is being implemented as a class-static function under the hood? Does that mean it's also getting an implicit argument (this)?

I did not know Mockito can't mock static methods though, good to know!

Comment: Yes. Exactly like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! For anyone else who doesn't want to take Rafal's word for it (I always like to have multiple sources), here is a post explaining:

https://android.jlelse.eu/the-ugly-truth-about-extension-functions-in-kotlin-486ec49824f4